# Why Typescript tries to match one branch of conditional type with another?

Tags: typescript, return-type, conditional-types

I have a small utility function and now I'm trying to write a little more specific type for it, using generics.

Here is a code:

```js
/* global localStorage */

const ls = localStorage

export type ParsedJSON<T> = T | null
export type Falsy = false | undefined

function get<T = any> (
  key: string,
  parseJSON?: boolean
): typeof parseJSON extends Falsy ? string : ParsedJSON<T> {
  const value = ls.getItem(key) ?? ''

  if (parseJSON === true) {
    let result: ParsedJSON<T> = null

    try {
      result = JSON.parse(value)
    } catch (err) {}

    return result
  } else if ((parseJSON === false)) {
    return value
  }

  return null
}
```

I've got an error for the else branch: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ParsedJSON<T>'`.

(An **else** branch is a little bit redundant here, but I added it explicitly to investigate this error).

[image]

I can't understand here, why TS tries to match the `string` type with the `ParsedJSON<T>` type.

The only reasonable explanation for me is that `false` is not assignable to the `Falsy` type, so that return type is calculated as `ParsedJSON<T>`. But I've checked that this is not the case:

[image]

So please, help me to understand what is going on here. )
Thanks.

Comment: Not a solution to this problem, but I think you should consider function overloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that what's happening is that TS evaluates the type expression `typeof parseJSON extends Falsy ? string : ParsedJSON<T>` not as a conditional expression to be evaluated with the generic parameters when the function is called, but immediately based on the currently available information about the function.

With this knowledge we can determine what the compiler infers the return type to be. The expression is

```
typeof parseJSON extends Falsy ? string : ParsedJSON<T>
```

`parseJSON`'s type at the time of evaluation is `boolean | undefined`, therefore it does *not* extend `Falsy` which is `false | undefined` and therefore a narrower type.

Therefore `get`'s return type is determined to be simply: `ParsedJSON<T>`.

The only way I can think of having a conditional return type based on the actual parameter values at the call site is with, as @Nishant suggested, function overloads. E.g.:

```
function get<T = any>(key: string, parseJSON: true): ParsedJSON<T>
function get<T = any>(key: string, parseJSON?: false): string
function get<T = any>(key: string, parseJSON?: boolean) {
  const value = ls.getItem(key) ?? ''

  if (parseJSON === true) {
    let result: ParsedJSON<T> = null

    try {
      result = JSON.parse(value)
    } catch (err) { }

    return result
  } else if ((parseJSON === false)) {
    return value
  }

  return null
}
```

Now the function will have the correct return type based on `parseJSON`'s type.

```
get<number>('', true) // => ParsedJSON<number>
get<number>('', false) // => string
get<number>('') // => string
```

[See this code in the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBA5gNg9gRgQymWBjJBlALjATgiAUzBGACgzUYA7AZyxVrAF4UZ0ps8DCLCAPAA54GWAJ6DiABQS5ahACYApDAHkAcgB4AKgD4WYbWAA+YagFcoUMgOG5RE4gDEktMQYBmr4qfPUFhB4AltSKFGQefqhYQTSQhFg6BgjUYroAFADWhGIAXGD0uCEQADRggrLyKhr5WLjmhACU+TJyitVaehFRMXFEiUasKWlZOfmFxWUVbR0A-PleUPLNBXXF3dTRsdTxA8mpGdl5q0XUpeWVhHP5cDAwUIQpjWAA3mRgYFR0DABuSA0GJYAOn6AEksIQALajMTPWazMAAckRFA+QQ8YHS0yqanULGYrDqDWebw+HweDFwhFoliwLUuylxOn0rAsVlRZLq7lJZI+VJpUAYrA6QOxhHSfygxPeZIAvp8EFhUAALTGEXC4ElgWUcvkJcy4Hb82ky+WEJbEdGYrGXDr41iLZYkmV6rAGnaShqmjlUt2GsyWaw6sj9TQWSFwdUZZFlIlNMDAYAsfSteSMjRh8wRqMhhKZ7O4aOIsqO+OJ5Mndah8ORwvpZHPcvMfQTM5AA)